# How to show all user list on template in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to show registered users/company name list to template in django. i am new in working with django forms.
I had registered successfully company by using template now i want to show all the company name which has been registered.
my models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id=models.IntegerField(default=0,primary_key=True)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    company_email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True,null=True)
```

i am stuck that how can i show all information on template using forms. how can i make form for this and how can i get all companies name to show

I wrote this to get all companies name

```
def allcompanies(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method =='GET':
        all_company=comoanyForm(request.GET)

        data=Company.objects.all()
        print "print all data",data

    else:
        pass

    return render_to_response(
            'allcompany.html',
            { },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

i get values in data but did not showing on template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using render_to_response - it is likely to be depreciated in the future.
You should be using render.

```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   return render(request, 'allcompany.html', {'data': data,})
```

then within your template you should have something like:

```
{% for company in data %}
    {{company.company_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

You should do the django tutorial (or refer to it) if you haven't already, these are simple concepts.

Comment: Thanks @Georgina S

Comment: all compaines comes in one row how can i show them in new line

Comment: {{company.company_name}}<br>      - br is a linebreak in html.